# Meaning of indices in set notation (inside and outside braces)

Tags: notation

I often encounter notation when dealing with sets of the form

$$\{G_i\}_{i=1}^6$$

Can someone please explain what the inner and outer indices refer to?

An *ideal* answer would directly parse the above expression into plain English phrasing.

(Aside: If helpful for any elaborations, this particular example I took from a probability question where $G$ represents an event.)

Comment: $$\{G_i\}_{i=1}^6 = \{G_1,G_2,G_3,G_4,G_5,G_6\}  \text{,}$$ the set whose elements are $G_i$ as $i$ ranges from $1$ to $6$.

Comment: I would appreciate a link to that probability question. It is a bit hard to tell what *they* meant, without some context. It could be what @EricTowers said. It could also be a sequence/$6$-tuple $(G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_6)$ abusing the curly braces where there should've been round ones.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I did not link to the question because it is not publicly available and did not type it out in full since I believed it was needlessly long for my purposes. Summarily $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^6$ represents the 6 possible genotype combinations of 2 parents where each parent in turn has a combination of a pair of the A and a alleles given that _at least_ one allele is A.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you for your comment, which answers my question perfectly. If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it.